# How to disable calendar from been selected in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, date, jquery-ui, input

I have an HTML `<input />` with `type=date` and I'm trying to use javascript to disable an array of dates but for some reason, it is not working and not sure where I got it wrong, below is my code:

```js
var array = ["2022-08-25", "2022-08-22", "2022-08-21"]

$('input[type="date"][name="tester"]').datepicker({
  beforeShowDay: function(date) {
    var string = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', date);
    return [array.indexOf(string) == -1]
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script   src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.1/jquery-ui.min.js"   integrity="sha256-eTyxS0rkjpLEo16uXTS0uVCS4815lc40K2iVpWDvdSY="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<input type="date" name="tester">
```

Comment: Define "not working". Use an input type=text instead of type=date. Also consider using an ID, which should be much more efficient than selecting on other attributes.

Comment: In additional notes from the API: *Creating a datepicker on an `<input type="date">` is not supported due to a UI conflict with the native picker.*

Answer (score 0):

> Creating a datepicker on an `<input type="date">` is not supported due to a UI conflict with the native picker.

See more: https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Consider the following.

```js
var array = ["2022-08-25", "2022-08-22", "2022-08-21"]

$('input[name="tester"]').datepicker({
  beforeShowDay: function(date) {
    var string = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', date);
    return [array.indexOf(string) === -1]
  }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="tester">
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but for some reason on click of the input form the calendar pop-up didn't show. Can you help?

Comment: @mideveloper Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example